# изменение картинки рабочего стола после нажатии кнопки на visual studio

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

здравствуйте я создаю приложение я ни как не могу понять как сделать изменение картинки рабочего стола после нажатии кнопки я пробивал поискать в гугле но нет точного способа только у вас есть надежда

вот мой код:

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;



namespace test_app
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            this.FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.FixedSingle;
        }
        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Накрутка призошла успешно!");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Для начала уточните, рабочего стола чего? Винды? Какой?

Comment: Винды мне нужно

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1061682/12888024